# Tor browser bundle/Mac OSX new installation: Unable to find the proxy server

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, mac

First-time user here. Dowloaded tor browser bundle (for OSX), launched: "Unable to find the proxy server". Added TorBrowser to exceptions for firewall, restarted, relaunched, "unable to find the proxy server." My connection is otherwise fine (at home), no other proxy/VPN installed on this machine. Scoured the internet and this site to see if some configuration is necessary after installation (read through documentation, etc) but can find no info--it all just says install and go!

Settings/"configure proxies to access the internet" is set (by default) "use system proxy settings." I tried all other proxy options, same problem. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently downloaded Tor browser for Mac OS too and had the exact same issue. That was my first time downloading and I had done it from the Tor page where it lists the download options for all of the operating systems. I know I had downloaded the mac option but for whatever reason it still did not work. I went back a second time and instead just clicked to download Tor from the big download button at the main page and all of the processes was the same but that time it did the trick and it startes up as it should now.

Also once you do get it running correctly remember to click on the onion on the top left of the browser to change security from low to high!:)

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix the problem. Guessing it's a network configuration issue, but I can't find any instructions or information anywhere about how to set this up properly.